# D3.js - How can I prevent Circles & Text Overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For each json a circle is created and x & y are randomly put out

```
for(var d = 0; d<json.length; d++){
circlexloc[d] = ((Math.random()*2*r)-r);
circleyloc[d] = ((Math.random()*2*r)-r);
};
```

Declaring a circle variable, whilst setting attributes & animation

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(json)

circle.enter().append('circle')
```

Animation

```
circle.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .attr('opacity',0.6)
  .attr('r', 5)

  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return circlexloc[i] })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {return circleyloc[i] });

circle.exit().transition().duration(1000)
  .attr('opacity',0)
  .attr("r",0)
  .remove();
```

Attach the technology to the circles

```
 var text = svg.selectAll('text')
text.data(json)
.enter().append("svg:text")
.style("font-size", "10px")
.text(function(d) { return d.TechName; })
.transition().duration(1000) 
.attr('opacity', 1)       
.attr("x", function (d, i) { return (circlexloc[i]+6)})
.attr("y", function (d, i) { return (circleyloc[i]+4)});
```

});

At the moment at times the tend to over lap each other. How can I prevent this? Suggestions & examples will be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent them from overlapping at any point during the transistion or only preventing overlap at the end of the transition?

Comment: Hi @Bill at the end of transistions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a couple of different options, depending on what exactly you are going after.

One way is to use a force directed layout which applies forces to the nodes to make sure that they don't overlap after reaching a steady state (note that they may overlap as they are getting to the steady state).  You can see an example of this at http://bl.ocks.org/1377729. Note that you can fully customize what the nodes look like and eliminate the lines.

I created an example of the forced based layout at http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/2/. With a force based layout you need to add the nodes first.

```
   force
       .nodes(nodes)
       .start();
```

And then update their locations for each force recalculation.

```
   force.on("tick", function() {

     text.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 6; })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 4; });           

     node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
         .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
   });
```

The other option is to use a `pack` layout like the example at http://bl.ocks.org/1628131. This layout will pack the circles tightly together and ensure that they don't overlap.

Comment: Could you possibly apply the force directed layout to what I have posted, it would be a huge help and much appreciated.

Comment: Added an example of force based node layout to my answer.

Comment: Hi Bill thanks that really helped a lot. But when I try to input d3 get json function it doesn't appear... edited example : http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/3/ .. i changed all the data(nodes) to (json) & it appears 'cannot read property length of null'

Comment: What does `json` look like from the `d3.json` call? Did you update the graph to use the `json` variable instead of `nodes`? Are you getting errors in the console? Is your json call succeeding?

Comment: This a snippet of the json: [{"TechName":"","id":1}]. I'm sure I did and on the console its says the following: 'cannot read property length of null'. It says its something to do with the force start

Comment: Make sure `json` is what you think it is and make sure you update `force.nodes(nodes)` to be `force.nodes(json)`.  You'll also need to update `data(nodes)` to `data(json)` and `d.techName` to `d.TechName`. If there is a problem with `start` then either what you are passing in is `null` or not an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks, it was stupidly just changing the TechName! Thanks again. Although, it appears when faced with lengthy words json overlaps time-to-time when run multiple times - have i changed anything? - http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/4/

Comment: My example doesn't do anything with label placement (I just hardcoded it like you did). If you want to make sure labels don't overlap, you'll need to add a force to them as well (similar to http://bl.ocks.org/1377729).

Comment: I see so I've been only putting forces on the circles.. so I would have to make var force2 etc for the labels